# JavaScript: Extract part of string between two optional characters with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a regex in javascript for capturing part of the string between two optional characters.

Optional characters are: '=' and '||'

Scenarios:

- LENGTH=A simple message||5
- LENGTH=A simple message
- LENGTH||5

For getting the value after '||' I manage that with the split() function.

For getting the 'A simple message' part I manage to extract the string with the regex `match(/\=(.*)\|\|/).pop()` when both '=' and '||' are in the string.

Any suggestions for extracting the string with one regex when one of the two optional characters is there?

I tried also `/(\=)?(.*)(\|\|)?/`but is not working.

Comment: What is expected output for `LENGTH||5`?

Comment: @anubhava The expected output for LENGTH||5 should be Null. Because I got the value after || with a split function but if its possible to have it in the same regex with the part between/after character '=' and '||' it will be nice.

Comment: Will [`=((?:(?!\|\|).)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/uH6oV7/1) work for you?

Comment: @Wiktor Oh this is nice. It is working fine. Is it possible to have an explanation of this regex?

Comment: @Panagiotis: You do not need that whole regex, only a part of it. Look, the point is that you need to check if there is `=` in the string. If not, the `value` is NULL, else, use `=((?:(?!\|\|).)*)`, or a more efficient one - `=([^|]*(?:\|(?!\|)[^|]*)*)`

Comment: @anubhava Yes this is working fine thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex to capture value from `=` and optional `||`:

```
/=((?:(?!\|\|).)*)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH6oV7/1)

Comment: Or a much better one - `=([^|]*(?:\|(?!\|)[^|]*)*)`. Tempered greedy tokens are best served unrolled.

Comment: But that also matches `LENGTH` in 3rd line which OP doesn't want.

Comment: These are standalone strings. Add `\n` into each `[...]` and you will see the difference if you test against a multiline input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers and explanations guys.

Comment: Oh, another one that will work with standalone strings: [`=(.*?)(?:\|\|.*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/uH6oV7/2). Looks simpler.

Answer (score 2):

This should probably do what you want:

```
^LENGTH(?:=([^|]*))?(?:\|\|(\d+))?$
```

This will match both the part between `LENGTH=` and `||` and the part after that. Both will be returned in the result, when present.

Example:

```
[
    "LENGTH=A simple message||5",
    "LENGTH=A simple message",
    "LENGTH||5"
].forEach(function(string)
{
    var result = string.match(/^LENGTH(?:=([^|]*))?(?:\|\|(\d+))?$/);
    console.log("found:",result[1],result[2]);
});
```

Of course, there are a few assumptions here regarding the actual format of the data.

Output:

```
found: A simple message / 5
found: A simple message / undefined
found: undefined / 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: Actually, this [`=(.*?)(?:\|\|.*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/uH6oV7/2) is a more generic version of the expression in this answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, not quite, since you expect the `=` to be there, which I don't (my regex will return the part after the `||` if present even if the `=` part isn't there).

Comment: Ok, so it does not actually answer OP question then, as OP expects Null in such cases.

Comment: It will return undefined for the given field whenever it's missing.

Comment: Edited the answer to illustrate what the regex returns in the 3 examples provided by the OP.